# Search Listview subitem with string

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Listview that contains all the guests from the database

```
        public FormGuestManagement()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        listViewGuests.View = View.Details;
        listViewGuests.GridLines = true;
        listViewGuests.Scrollable = true;
        listViewGuests.FullRowSelect = true;
        listViewGuests.HideSelection = false;
        var guests = Repository.GetAllGuests();

        foreach (var guest in guests)
        {
            ListViewItem lvData = new ListViewItem(guest.AccountID.ToString());

            lvData.SubItems.Add(guest.Username);
            lvData.SubItems.Add(guest.Email);
            lvData.SubItems.Add(guest.FirstName);
            lvData.SubItems.Add(guest.LastName);
            lvData.SubItems.Add(guest.TelephoneNumber);
            lvData.SubItems.Add(guest.AddressLine1);
            lvData.SubItems.Add(guest.AddressLine2);
            lvData.SubItems.Add(guest.City);
            lvData.SubItems.Add(guest.State);
            lvData.SubItems.Add(guest.Postcode);
            lvData.SubItems.Add(guest.Country);

            listViewGuests.Items.Add(lvData);
        }
    }
```

How would it be possible to search one single column (in this case guest.Firstname) with a string and only show the values that match the string (hide the others) in the listview?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Use `DataGridView` instead of `ListView`.

Comment: If it's a standard WinForms ListView then I don't believe that the ListViewItem control has a .Hide or .Visible method. There is a .Remove but this actually removes the item from the list. Possibly you could just rebuild the list every time the user clears the selection string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ListView` control does not provide the functionality you want.  In order to simulate what you describe, you would have to rebuild the desired list every time a filter condition changes.

Or you could do as one commenter suggested and use something more robust, such as a `DataGridView`.  This control provides true Row/Column behaviors and takes a `DataSource` that can be bound.

Comment: Thank you, I made a new query in my repository that looks up a guest by name in the database and recreates the list and that worked :)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with LINQ and should be very easy:

```
using System.Linq;


var result = guests.Where(guest => guest.FirstName.Equals("Test"));
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.